# How can I add one DataColumn in two different DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add one DataColumn in two different DataTable, but it is giving me error and saying that "Column 'imgCount' already belongs to another DataTable". Can I do this? here is my code.

```
DataTable dtS = new DataTable();
DataTable dtF = new DataTable();
DataColumn imgCount = new DataColumn("imgCount",Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
imgCount.DefaultValue = 0;
dtS = dvSho.ToTable("shooters");
dtS.Columns.Add(imgCount);
dtF = dvFys.ToTable("fyshwick");
dtF.Columns.Add(imgCount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add a single column instance to the DataTables.

Create separate instances for the two tables.

```
DataColumn imgCount = new DataColumn("imgCount",Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
DataColumn imgCount2 = new DataColumn("imgCount",Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

dtS = dvSho.ToTable("shooters");
dtS.Columns.Add(imgCount);

dtF = dvFys.ToTable("fyshwick");
dtF.Columns.Add(imgCount2);
```